# Java boolean statement

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

Just wondering what the output of this would be and why? I understand that 
true
true
will be printed, but I'm unsure how if(flag1 && flag2) can be evaluated? Is there a way this statement can be expanded so I can understand what it really means? Thank you!

```
public class project{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean flag1 = isHoopy(202);
        boolean flag2 = isFrabjuous(202);
        System.out.println(flag1);
        System.out.println(flag2);
        if (flag1 && flag2) {
        System.out.println("ping!");
        }
        if (flag1 || flag2) {
        System.out.println("pong!");
        }
        }

        public static boolean isHoopy(int x) {
        boolean hoopyFlag;
        if (x%2 == 0) {
        hoopyFlag = true;
        } else {
        hoopyFlag = false;
        }
        return hoopyFlag;
        }

        public static boolean isFrabjuous(int x) {
        boolean frabjuousFlag;
        if (x > 0) {
        frabjuousFlag = true;
        } else {
        frabjuousFlag = false;
        }
        return frabjuousFlag;
        }

}
```

Comment: It should also print `ping! pong!`, and you will see this by stepping through the code with a debugger.

Comment: What is not clear about `flag1 && flag2`? If you do not know what `&&` means you really should first work through a beginners book/tutorial.

Comment: I understand what && means, however I was just thrown by the if statement not really presenting a condition as I'm used to e.g. if(x > 10). I can see now that it doesn't need to be presented such as if(flag1 == true) etc.

Answer (score 2):

Going back to basics operators for java && is the operator which stands for 'AND' operator if we talk about Digital world. In java terms && is logical AND operator comparing boolean values of operands only.  It takes two operands indicating a boolean value and makes a lazy evaluation on them.'&&' only performs the 2nd test if the first is also true.
Taking an example

You can compare && operation to multiply in simple maths that says

1 = true

0 = false

1*1 = 1 => true && true = true

1*0 = 0 => true && false = false

0*0 = 0 => false && false = false

0*1 = 0 => false && true =  false

**Is there a way this statement can be expanded so I can understand what it really means?**

Now if(flag1 && flag2)
Java evaluates flag1 first.If it finds flag1 true then only it will move to check flag2 as if it finds flag1 is false there is no use checking flag2, as in any case result is going to be false.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging the code could have explained everything to you. I am providing some here:

```
boolean flag1 = isHoopy(202); // flag1 = true
boolean flag2 = isFrabjuous(202); // flag2 = true

System.out.println(flag1); // prints: true
System.out.println(flag2); // prints: true

if (flag1 && flag2) { // true && true = true, so this will be evaluated
    System.out.println("ping!"); // prints: ping!
}

if (flag1 || flag2) { // true || true = true, so this will be evaluated
    System.out.println("pong!"); // prints: pong!
}
```

**Improvements:**

You could shortened the methods:

```
public static boolean isHoopy(int x) {
    return (x % 2 == 0);
}

public static boolean isFrabjuous(int x) {
    return (x > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The combination of two boolean variables can have 4 possibilities (2^2=4):

false, false (00 in binary notation)
false, true (01 in binary notation)
true, false (10 in binary notation)
true, true (11 in binary notation)

In your code, you have only one combination: true, true (11)

You may have other cases, for example like this:

For false, false (00):

```
flag1 = isHoopy(201);
flag2 = isFrabjuous(-202);
```

For false, true (01):

```
flag1 = isHoopy(201);
flag2 = isFrabjuous(202);
```

For true, false (10):

```
flag1 = isHoopy(202);
flag2 = isFrabjuous(-202);
```